# Flutter: How to left align View Port in PageView

Tags: flutter, flutter-pageview, pagersnaphelper

### How it works

When we set viewportFraction, the view gets center aligned.

**If viewportFraction sets**

```
PageView(
   viewportFraction: 0.8
)
```

[Center-Aligned view port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRaLO.jpg)

### How I expect

But what I need is the view to start with left-aligned like how playstore dashboard works.

[Left-Aligned view port](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/60136315/75988599-d8898880-5f17-11ea-9a40-ca42b84f3ab7.png)

The above screenshot has taken from the Google Play Store.

### For more info

How can I achieve this?

While doing a coding walkthrough, I've never found a way to center align it.
I just created a new custom class by just copying the *page_view* class.

Comment: For those who look for this, please follow this feature request https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/52014